# Meaning of "так"?

Tags: грамматика

Can someone provide good explanation about word - "так"? For example what does word "так" means in "Меня так не з<strike>а</strike>*о*вут", or "Вот так", or "Так вот". Maybe someone knows good article or something about word "так".

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/так

Comment: http://www.classes.ru/all-russian/dictionary-russian-academ-term-79625.htm

Comment: Sometimes it means "yes" like it does in Polish (as in "yes, so it is").

Answer (score 6):

Roughly speaking it's translated as `so` (as it is mentioned in other answer here) or `this/that way`:

- Со мной никто так не будет обращаться - Nobody will treat me that way.
- [нужно делать] вот так! - [one should do it] this way!
- Так вот надо использовать топор - Here's how it is supposed to use an axe.
- Вот так я стал моряком - this is how I became a sailor.

Answer (score 5):

i'm sure there's translation of the word in the Ru-En dictionary, one of which is `so`

> Меня так не зoвут - They don't call me so
>
> Вот так - Like so
>
> Так вот - So

Comment: In English we would not say " They don't call me so".  Translation websites offer these alternate versions, which don't look too bad: "That is not my name."  "I am not called that."